# Show a drop down in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am creating a django form which consists of a field that is related with another model via Foreign Key.
Originally it is showing a dropdown of all the instances from the related model but I want to show only those fields which are connected with the user for that I am using this code.

Forms.py

```
class OutwardDocketForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OutwardDocket
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ["created_by"]


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(OutwardDocketForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            print("self")
            self.fields['sending_location'].queryset = Receiver_client.objects.filter(emitter=self.request.user.id)
```

But It doesn't seem to be working as it still shows the complete dropdown as opposed to what is required

Models.py

```
class OutwardDocket(models.Model):
    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    dispatch_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    sending_location = models.ForeignKey(Receiver_client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver_location')

class Receiver_client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    emitter = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client')
```

How can I show the dropdown which is related to the particular user?

Comment: You need to use the `queryset` argument of a `forms.ModelChoiceField`. AFAIK you can't do that using a straightforward `ModelForm`, you'll need  to explicitly declare it. You'll also have to pass the current user when you instantiate the form.

Comment: @nigel222 okay and how do I do that ?